# How do I auto increment my own results column from a max value in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
select MAX (cast (id as numeric)) from table --whatever value it may return

select 
(row_number ()  over (order by id)) as Number from table  --will start at 1
```

How do I combine the two so whatever value the first query returns, I can use that value and auto increment from there, somehow combining the two (tried nesting them, but unsuccessful) or do I need to...

1. Declare a variable
2. get my max id value
3. make my variable equal to that
4. then place that value/variable in my second statement?

Like...

```
select 
(row_number ()  over (order by id) + (declared_max_value)) as Number from table
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what your desired result is?

Comment: example, whatever my max value is (unknown) let say it's 900 so then each row would increment from that value;

Comment: if there were 5 rows returned, then column one (Number column) would display --> 901,902,903,904,905

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Seed.ID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by T.ID) as Number,
    T.ID
FROM
    T CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID FROM T) AS Seed
```

Working sample: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a14ad/3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE as
(SELECT max(Field) FROM Table)
    SELECT WhatYouWant, cte.m FROM Table2
    INNER JOIN CTE ON 0=0
```

or this:

```
SELECT *, t.maxField FROM Table1 OUTER APPLY (SELECT max(Field) as maxField FROM Table2) t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @maxValue int
select @maxValue = select max(cast (id as integer)) from table

declare @uaerystring varchar(max)
select @queryString = 
'(row_number ()  over (order by id) + '
+ @maxValue +
')as Number from table'
Execute(@queryString)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T Table (ID int , Value Varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Value)
VALUES (50, 'Value1'), (500, 'Value1'), (100, 'Value1'), (50, 'Value2'), (100, 'Value2'),(500, 'Value2')

;with CTE (Value, ID, rn)
AS
(
SELECT Value, MAX(ID), rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Value ASC)
FROM 
@T
GROUP BY Value
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```